# Get Xamarin Essentials WebAuthenticator User Profile Data

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I´m using WebAuthenticator from Xamarin Essentials to authenticate users using Google and Facebook accounts.

In Xamarin Essentials WebAuthenticator Sample, the app get the authenticated user token, but I need to know how to get these profile sections:

Profile Picture
Name (Full Name or First and Last Name)
Email

How can I get these profile data?

Comment: After you get the `AccessToken`,i think you could request for the profile data with it.You could look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63213480/10768653),something like the method in the question.

Comment: Hi @LeoZhu-MSFT, I've seen this plugin before and even used it, but I really want to use fewer plugins in my app. This is why I´m using Web Authenticator. With Xamarin Essential and Web Authenticator I don't need any other external packages.

Comment: I mean you could use `HttpClient` to request the profile data like the `GetUserFromFacebookAsync` method in the link above.